# What happens to a signal for a process in "D" state (or TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, scheduling

What happens to a signal (e.g. SIGALRM) for a process in "D" state (or TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE)?

Are they ignored or are they delayed for when the process exits "D" state?

Can you point me to corresponding lines in a kernel source code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE: The proccess is waiting on certain special cases of event, such as completion of of a disk I/O. If signal is generated (including SIGSTOP and SIGKILL) for a process in this state, then **the signal is not delivered** until the process emerges from this state.

Comment: Thank you. I even have that book, but forgot to look there.